# SOSL not returning record in test

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests, sosl

I have `EditorModalController.searchDoctors` that returns a list of contacts.

```
public class EditorModalController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> searchDoctors(String searchValue) {
        String s = '*' + searchValue + '*';
        String doctorRecordTypeId = Schema.Sobjecttype.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Doctor').getRecordTypeId();

        List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND :s IN ALL Fields
                RETURNING Contact (Id, FirstName, LastName, NPI__c, MailingCity, MailingState WHERE RecordTypeId =: doctorRecordTypeId)];

        return searchList[0];
    }     
}
```

This function works great in my lightning component. I've tried to apply test coverage

```
@isTest
private class EditorModalControllerTest {

    @testSetup private static void setup() {
        String doctorRecordTypeId = Schema.Sobjecttype.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Doctor').getRecordTypeId();
        insert new Contact(LastName = 'MCDANIEL', RecordTypeId = doctorRecordTypeId);
    }        

    @isTest private static void searchDoctors() {
        System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT count() FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'MCDANIEL']);
        System.assertEquals(1, EditorModalController.searchDoctors('MCDANIEL').size()); 
    }    
}
```

The first assert passes, but the second does not. I don't understand why that is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SOSL doesn't return results in test classes, so you have to use special methods to set the results.

> To ensure that test methods always behave in a predictable way, any
>   Salesforce Object Search Language (SOSL) query that is added to an
>   Apex test method returns an empty set of search results when the test
>   method executes. If you do not want the query to return an empty list
>   of results, you can use the Test.setFixedSearchResults system method
>   to define a list of record IDs that are returned by the search.

e.g.

```
   Id [] fixedSearchResults= new Id[1];
   fixedSearchResults[0] = '001x0000003G89h';
   Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);
   List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND 'test' 
                                     IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
                                        Account(id, name WHERE name = 'test' LIMIT 1)];
```

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm

Answer (score 4):

This is "by design" apparently. See the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm) for the reason and how to simulate results using `Test.setFixedSearchResults`.